# Formulae to search for 12 and 13 in a range

Tags: google-sheets

using formula:

```
=LET(data,transpose(filter('Arbor Feed Tutor List'!A:A,(SEARCH("13", 'Arbor Feed Tutor List'!A:A))) ),
IFNA(REDUCE(TOROW(,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),LAMBDA(a,i,HSTACK(a,INDEX(data,,i),"HP's",INDEX(data,,i),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()+1)))))))
```

to search for cells which contain text "13" in them

How could I modify this to search for cells containing text "13" OR "12"
Tried the obvious using an OR function, no joy.

Thanks

Tried:
=LET(data,transpose(filter('Arbor Feed Tutor List'!A:A,(SEARCH(OR("13, "12"), 'Arbor Feed Tutor List'!A:A))) ),
IFNA(REDUCE(TOROW(,1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),LAMBDA(a,i,HSTACK(a,INDEX(data,,i),"HP's",INDEX(data,,i),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()+1)))))))

Comment: Some  data to play with might help.

Comment: Why? It's a formula, the data itself doesn't matter. It's solved, implimented and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `SEARCH("13", 'Arbor Feed Tutor List'!A:A` with:

```
REGEXMATCH( 'Arbor Feed Tutor List'!A:A,"12|13")
```

It will return true if any of those values are found in the string

Comment: Merci. Seems to work perfect